# What does "right out the window" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was listening "**In the End**" by **Linkin Park**, and they sing "**Watch the time go right out the window**".

My question is:
Is it literally outside the window or, in this context does it mean something else?

Maybe something like: right there, over there, or so fast.

Is it an idiom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something goes "out the window" when it is lost or disregarded.  For instance

> When he saw how it rained, his resolve to go for a walk went right out the window.

or

> When they got into an argument, their agreement to be nicer to each other went right out the window.

Answer (score 1):

To “go out the window” is an idiom for being discarded or lost, like something tossed or sucked out the open window of a moving vehicle.